# What are .py~ files in Python

Tags: python-2.7, compilation

What are the file.py~ files created in the same directory when i write and run a file.py?

Is this something UNIX-specific (i am using Debian).

Comment: Some editors create backup files with this extension. What is your text editor?

Comment: I believe gedit uses this for backups of the previous save. Are you using that?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida I am using Emacs.

Comment: Then you may read about your `~` files here: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupDirectory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically files ending with a ~ are backups. See this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76189/what-does-the-tilde-mean-at-the-end-of-a-filename